# How to Center Text in Multiline Labels

Tags: qgis, labeling

I used wrap text on "~" and now I have two lines of text from one attribute field. Is there a way to center that and not just choosing center as the horizontal alignment? QGIS 1.8.

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with choosing center as alignment.

Comment: I just moves the control point and doesn't center the text.

Comment: What do you mean by control point?

Comment: If you can upload a image that helps.

Comment: The Control point is what I called the blue square in the center. I was hoping to get the "City of" centered over "Newburgh".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the alignment with the wrapping properties

[image]

Note: This is only in the current dev build not in 1.8.

Answer (score 4):

Not in QGIS 1.8. Multi-line text alignment for labels is a new feature in 1.9 (i.e. upcoming 2.0 release, since 1.9 is not going to be released). Currently, the Change Label Properties dialog (in 1.9) does not include the multi-line properties capable of being set at the layer level.